# How to join / leave a group in SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I use `SignalR` un my Angular project and I can join a group by invoking a `Hub` method called JoinGroup.

***service.ts:***

```
private startConnection(): any {      

    this.connection
        .start()
        .done((data: any) => {
            this.proxy.invoke('JoinGroup', 'demoGroup'); //join user to a group
        })
}
```

***Hub.cs:***

```
public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}

public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

Similarly there is also Leave group method in my hub. However, I have no idea when can I call this method on client side as I do for JoinGroup. Of course I know that there are `OnConnected()`, `OnReconnected()` and `OnDisconnected()` methods in my hub and I can pass group name on  connection. But I want to know that how to leave a user from group and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When to remove a connection from a group depends on your specific scenario. For example, you may want to remove the connection from a group when the user navigates away from a page, etc.

But group membership does not persist across different connections. This means you don't need to manually leave groups when you disconnect a SignalR connection. When you disconnect (whether intentional or due to an error), all memberships in groups will be lost. Quoting [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-2.2#groups-in-signalr):

> Group membership isn't preserved when a connection reconnects. The connection needs to rejoin the group when it's re-established.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you mean that there is no need to remove a user from a group? On the other hand, I also wonder that is there a similar event on client side that I can determine to call LeaveGroup method. As it seen, I connect to a group on connection.on event. What about leaving from this group?

Comment: Group is a collection of connections connected to a server or server cluster, so only the server knows about groups and can remove members from a group. A client can only invoke server methods to remove membership from groups.

Comment: A client leaves all groups automatically when it disconnects. Whether you need to manually remove from groups depends on your business logic: if there is a need to maintain the SignalR connection but unsubscribe from push notifications targeted at a group, then you need to manually call server methods to remove from the group.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the SignalR hub issue on [SignalR : Cannot access default hub methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286047/signalr-cannot-access-default-hub-methods)?