# SignalR : Cannot access default hub methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

In my Angular project use TypedHub interface (called IDemoHubTypedClient) in my project as shown below:

***IDemoHubTypedClient:***

```
public interface IDemoHubTypedClient
{
    Task BroadcastData(object data);

    Task SendMessageToClient(string title, string name, string message);
}
```

However, as I inherited from `Hub<IDemoHubTypedClient>` instead of `Hub`, I cannot access to the default hub methods i.e. `SendAsync()` as shown below and only access the methods in the `IDemoHubTypedClient` i.e. `BroadcastData()` and `SendMessageToClient()`. As I need to use this structure for using DI and TypedHub, how can I fix this problem? Should I add all the hub methods (`SendAsync()` etc.) in my `IDemoHubTypedClient`? As you know there is only seals of these methods as they are on client side (I call `BroadcastData()` method and this method is actually on client side). Any idea?

***DemoHub:***

```
public class DemoHub : Hub<IDemoHubTypedClient>
{
    public async Task SendMessageToAll(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(user, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must define all your client methods on the interface if you want to use strongly typed hub. AFAIK there is no way to "mix-and-match" between a strongly typed hub and a normal hub. If you have a client like this:

```
this.connection.on('receiveMessage', (message: string) => {
    // Do things
});

this.connection.on('receiveData', (data: MyData, message: string) => {
    // Do things
});
```

Then if you want to use strongly typed hub, you must define your strongly typed hub interface with methods using the same names and signatures (method names are case-insensitive):

```
public interface IDemoClient
{
    Task ReceiveMessage(string message);
    Task ReceiveData(MyData data, string message);
}
```

The advantage is that you can write `await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage("Hello from server!")` instead of `await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "Hello from server!")`. The whole point is that you don't have to hardcode the client method name and you get additional static type checking for the method parameters.

Comment: Great explanations, thanks a lot. İn this case I use the approach mentioned on **[Strongly typed hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#strongly-typed-hubs)**. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy. You need to ha a SignalR ConnectionManager ready (dependency injection), and get a typed HubContext from there, and then you can access the given Hub's functions. 
See more here: https://codeopinion.com/practical-asp-net-core-hubcontext/